# How to install ST-Link driver onto STM32 Discovery Board for Visual GDB Debugging

Tags: embedded, stm32, visualgdb

I am attempting to program a STM32VLDiscovery Board, using Visual Studio 2019, Visual GDB and STM32CubeMX. When I connect the board to the machine, it appears as 'USB Mass Storage Device'. I am using a Windows 10 VM. The program builds fine, but when I attempt to begin on-board debugging, I get an error message stating:

> USB Mass Storage Device" does not appear to have "ST-Link Driver"
>   driver installed. The debugger may have problems finding your decvice.
>   Try installing it now?

If I click yes, then a bit of software called UsbDriverTool.exe starts and a progress bar appears with the message

> VisualGDB is installing the following USB driver: **ST-Link Driver** the following device: **USB Mass Storage Device**

This then fails with the message

> Automatic driver installation gailed. Do you want to try installing it manually?

Clicking 'yes' again gets the message

> USB driver installation failed with code -532462766

And then finally

> open failed (no matching adapter found)

Can anyone tell me please, how I go about getting the ST-Link driver on to the discovery board so that I can start debugging my code?

(One other thing that may be relevant. I tried using the STM32 ST-Link Utility program to program the code on to the board. I find that it will only connect to the board if I am holding reset whilst I press the 'connect' button.

Comment: Thisd question is IMO offtopic as there is nor programming questions.

Comment: The driver is not installed "onto" the board, it is installed in Windows.  It should not appear as a "mass storage device", what does Windows Device Manager show it as?  This: https://os.mbed.com/questions/79227/Install-ST-LINK-drivers-on-Win7-after-ST/ may be relevant.  Anyhow it is a Windows driver installation issue, so off-topic.

Comment: @Clifford, Thanks for the response, but I'm pretty sure it's not a windows driver issue. I have installed all of the appropriate drivers from the ST site. Device manager lists it as a 'USB Mass Storage Device' under 'Universal Serial Bus Controllers' and also lists it under 'Disk Drives' as STM32.  When I pipe the USB connection through to my VM, virtualbox lists it as 'ST Microelectronics STM32 ST-Link'  Furthermore the error messages seem to clearly indicate that the driver is missing from the device, not from windows.

Comment: It is firmware on the ST-Link controller, there is no driver to install, though it is possible to update the firmware.  Sounds like you may have messed up the firmware on the ST-Link.  Possibly put the mbed bootloader on it?  Does it actually work as a mass storage device?  Either way I would try it without the VM - that just makes it even further off-topic.  Check it works in a conventioanl environment before complicating the issue I suggest.

Comment: I wonder if it presents as a USB composite device and having one device on the host and one on the VM causes a problem?